# How to make a vertical border in html/css using a gradient effect that stretches 100% height

Tags: html, css

So I'm building a layout for a club I belong to, anyways, the layout I'm using has an effect where a border stretches along side the entire page, but tampers out using gradient near the top and bottom. Here's the layout - what I'm referring to is the soft shadow on the left side of the page:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6809301/sogawebsite.jpg

I generally consider myself fairly proficient with html/css but I'm really struggling making this work. Without specifying explicitly height on the parent container, I can't get the border to stretch as the body expand. With the side border gradient we really have 3 pieces - the top which needs to dock to the top of the container, bottom which is docked to the bottom of the page - both can be made static height, and the middle which stays solid color but needs to stretch based on the height of the page.

Any help would be appropriated. I always felt that height based scaling was somewhat awkward in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible options is to use absolutely positioned generated content (`:before` for left "border", and `:after` for right one) with 100% height and [CSS Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients) as background of generated pseudoelements. For IE9 and lower, regular single-color borders can be used as a fallback.

See [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WT4a3/1/) for working example.

Comment: Would you possibly have an example of this (or something similar) being done? Never used :before selector to achieve this, a little confused how this would fit.

Comment: Sure. I've added live demo to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The smart way to do it is with [gradient borders](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/), specifically `border-image`. Browser support isn't perfect, but since this is a quite non-essential effect, a little graceful degradation wouldn't hurt for improved performance across the board.

Here is a little [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kxaLn).

I used [SASS (with Compass)](http://compass-style.org/) which will compile into CSS (minified!) and take care of the vendor prefixes for you:

```
div  
  border-width: 3px
  +border-image(linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), black, black, rgba(0,0,0,0)) 1 100%)
```

But, if you were a masochist you could do the CSS by hand:

```
div {
border-width: 3px;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(33.33333%, #000000), color-stop(66.66667%, #000000), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
border-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;}
```

If that doesn't work for you, look at some of the other techniques on CSS-tricks, or use images.